# comparison of Hash with Hash failed

Tags: ruby

Today I encountered an interesting issue:
When sorting an array of hashes, it fails with an error `comparison of Hash with Hash failed`. Example:

```
h1 = {a:1, b:2} 
h2 = {a:1, b:3} 
[h1, h2].sort ArgumentError: comparison of Hash with Hash failed
```

now, the weird thing is that both `==` and `eql?` succeed normally.

```
h1==h2
=> false

h1.eql?(h2)
=> false
```

What's even more weird is that the sort on the array succeeds if the hashes are the same:

```
h1= {a:1, b:2}
h2= {a:1, b:2}
[h1, h2].sort
=> [{:a=>1, :b=>2}, {:a=>1, :b=>2}]
```

I assume array sort doesn't use `eql?` internally. What does it use? Any explanation into why this is happening?

Comment: FWIW, the docs for `sort` explicitly states what it uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting depends on the ability to determine whether something is smaller, larger or equal, which is described as [Comparable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Comparable.html).

Hash is not comparable and calling `<=>` with two hashes returns nil.

Comment: It's interesting that `{} <=> {}` returns 0, but `{} <=> {a: 1}` returns nil

Answer (score 0):

Sort uses the spaceship operator `<=>`. The [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-sort) state:

> ... comparison between a and b and return an integer less than 0 when b follows a, 0 when a and b are equivalent, or an integer greater than 0 when a follows b

When you run the following, it returns nil:

```
{a:1, b:2} <=> {a:1, b:3}
#=> nil
```

Whereas if you do the same with an array, you get the correct result:

```
[1] <=> [2]
#=> -1
[2] <=> [2]
#=> 0
[3] <=> [2]
#=> 1
```

Hence the sort not working, as far as I'm aware.

As for the latter case, an array of equal hashes, I wonder if the method does an equality check before the sorting. I've had a look at the source, though don't know C, so perhaps someone more knowledgeable can confirm or refute this.